# Windows Identity SID

Tags: windows-identity, security-identifier

Does SID for a windows account (local, domain, Active Directory) ever changed once an account is created? If yes, under what conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can change when you migrate an account to a new domain.

That's what the `SidHistory` attribute in your AD account is for - you can look up all previous SIDs for that account.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679833%28VS.85%29.aspx for more details on the SidHistory attribute in AD.

Comment: Its is sad @marc_s that SIDs change. I've found from another question that there is `object-guid` in active directory records which never changes unless done manually or account recreated. Does such a thing exists for windows accounts (local or domain)?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: SID's are based (in part) on the domain SID, therefore, if you move an account from Domain A to Domain B, its SID has to change - no way around that. As long as you only have a single domain, this is not an issue. And yes - Active Directory accounts (domain accounts) have an `objectGUID` property.